# Create custom attribute same like related products in magento 2

Tags: magento2, attributes, custom, related-products

I want to create a custom attribute as ***"Similar product"*** which will behave like ***"Related products"*** attribute.

How can i do that in magento 2?

Answer (score 2):

You can use the below module for the Create your custom linked products type programmatically like (Related, Cross-sell, Upsell products).

Module: https://github.com/ibnab/magento2-custom-product-link

Explanation: https://www.ibnab.com/en/blog/magento-2/adminhtml-ui-create-your-custom-linked-products-type-like-related-crosssell-upsell-products

Hope this will work for you.

Comment: Yes, thank you. this is what i wanted. I will install this and check how it is working.

Comment: Your welcome, Also, Please accept the answer if it works for you.

Comment: I installed this, and worked as expected. but when i export the products, i did not find this custom attribute in my export csv. Also, when i want to import this attributes through csv , how will i do that?

Comment: For this, I think you have to override the default Export-Import functionality.

Answer (score 0):

Nice this is working for me thanks.Can you please show me how can i access this in the front end with this function.I want get all Custom link product ids in frontend.